# DRY - Code duplicated in recursive function: string replacer in dictionaries (python)

Tags: python, recursion

I am building a json token replacer, that works like this:

input: `{"greet": "hello {{name}}"}` and tokens `{"name": "Lorenzo"}`

output: `{"greet": "hello Lorenzo"}`

---

As I want the function to work also with nested dicts/lists, I've used recursion to extend the functionality on more complex inputs such as:

input: `{"a": {"b": "x{{ppp}}z"}}` and tokens `{"ppp": "y"})`

output: `{"a": {"b": "xyz"}}`

(other tests/example usages are available [here](https://github.com/lorenzua02/json-replacer/blob/main/test/tests.py#L27))

---

Even if the code works, I'm not satisfied with my current solution because I've violated the DRY principle.

I'm sure I can make my code cleaner: any ideas or suggestions? This is what I tried:

```py
def __replace(input_str: str, pytokens: dict):
    for k, v in pytokens.items():
        input_str = re.sub("{{" + k + "}}", str(v), input_str)
    return input_str


def __json_replacer(pyinput, pytokens: dict):
    # TODO DRY: code is doubled, code this part again
    if isinstance(pyinput, str):
        return __replace(pyinput, pytokens)

    if isinstance(pyinput, list):
        for i in range(len(pyinput)):
            pyinput[i] = __json_replacer(pyinput[i], pytokens)
        return pyinput

    if not isinstance(pyinput, dict):
        return pyinput

    res = {}
    for k, v in pyinput.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            v = __replace(v, pytokens)

        if isinstance(v, list):
            for i in range(len(v)):
                v[i] = __json_replacer(v[i], pytokens)

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = __json_replacer(v, pytokens)

        res[k] = v

    return res
```

Note: the project is open source! If you provide a solution, feel free to open a PR and take the credits :) [GitHub project link](https://github.com/lorenzua02/json-replacer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten

```
if not isinstance(pyinput, dict):
    return pyinput

res = {}
for k, v in pyinput.items():
    if isinstance(v, str):
        v = __replace(v, pytokens)

    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i in range(len(v)):
            v[i] = __json_replacer(v[i], pytokens)

    if isinstance(v, dict):
        v = __json_replacer(v, pytokens)

    res[k] = v
```

to

```
if isinstance(pyinput, dict):
    return {k: __json_replacer(v, pytokens) for k, v in pyinput.items()}
```

This would then delegate the list check to the code above, so make a small change to the list handler. Change this

```
if isinstance(pyinput, list):
    for i in range(len(pyinput)):
        pyinput[i] = __json_replacer(pyinput[i], pytokens)
    return pyinput
```

to

```
if isinstance(pyinput, list):
    return [__json_replacer(v, pytokens) for v in pyinput]
```

---

Putting it together

```
def __json_replacer(pyinput, pytokens):
    if isinstance(pyinput, str):
        return __replace(pyinput, pytokens)

    if isinstance(pyinput, list):
        return [__json_replacer(v, pytokens) for v in pyinput]

    if isinstance(pyinput, dict):
        return {k: __json_replacer(v, pytokens) for k, v in pyinput.items()}

    return pyinput
```

Running

```
>>> __json_replacer({"a": {"b": "x{{ppp}}z"}}, {"ppp": "y"})
# {'a': {'b': 'xyz'}}
```

As expected.

---

I would discourage treating the entire object as a string and perform string replacement since you may end up performing replacement operations on keys as well which could have unintended consequences (such as duplicating or corrupting keys).

Comment: This is much cleaner (and all my tests pass!): exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to take the credits opening a PR (project link above in the question), thank you! P.S.: Yea I agree: treating the entire object as a string is not an option

Comment: @LorenzoMogicato appreciate that, made a PR https://github.com/lorenzua02/json-replacer/pull/1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to treat the whole input as a `dict`. You can read the whole file as a `string` and just use the `__replace()` function.

Comment: almost feels like that json (as string) could be jinja template.

Comment: This could inadvertently change keys if they have "ppp" or whatever token, which will lead to unintended consequences (think duplicated keys, etc). This should be mentioned in the answer as a potential caveat as it is not perfect